# Delete specific record in SQLite3 DB matching two variables

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a Python script that writes to a SQLite3 database and the table is called `notify_users`, and it has two text-content columns, `language_code` and `username`.

Visualized, then, the `notify_users` database looks like this:

```
| language_code | username      |
---------------------------------
| de            | jane_doe      |
| sv            | jane_doe      |
| fi            | jane_doe      |
| de            | tom_petty     |
| zh            | tom_petty     |
```

What I'd like to do is be able to use **two criteria** (both the language_code and username) to delete a specific record.

For example, I'd like to delete the record that has *both* `jane_doe` in the `username` column and `de` in `language_code`.

```
| language_code | username      |
---------------------------------
| de            | jane_doe      | X
| sv            | jane_doe      |
| fi            | jane_doe      |
| de            | tom_petty     |
| zh            | tom_petty     |
```

How can I format a `DELETE FROM notify_users...` query appropriately to accomplish this task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can string together conditions using `and`:

```
conn.execute("""delete from notify_user 
                where language_code = ? and username = ?;""",('de','jane_doe'))
```

Comment: Thanks! My Python code is `sql = "DELETE FROM notify_users WHERE language_code = '{}' and username = '{}'".format(language_code, mauthor)` , that should work, right?

Comment: @JohnSmith: generally we shouldn't use `.format()` here because of the possibility of SQL Injection-attack. If it's just you using the code that will work.

Comment: Yeah, it's just me using the code, and the raw data to be passed on to those variables goes through a number of steps before it reaches the SQL query (the language_code is from a fixed set, for example). Thanks again!

Comment: I see. Ok. You're very welcome. You can feel free to accept this answer using the checkmark if it helped you.